# Scrapy and extracting a product image with a very obvious div/img/src

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

Okay, I pulled out everything I need from the side - except for the product photo.
What's going on here again?

Here we go....you can get an idea of the product image:

1. https://werkzeugstore24.de/makita-duc254z-akku-kettensaege-18-v-solo.html
2. My used (or tried) selectors:

> The photo is in the div container "img.fotorama__img" and links is in
> "src". I also went up in the div hierarchy - nothing. I did not find
> it.

```
response.css('img.fotorama__img::attr(src)').extract()
response.css('fotorama__img::attr(src)').extract()
response.css('.fotorama__stage__shaft::attr(src)').extract()
```

It was enough, then I went the hard way - XPATH!

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "fotorama__img", " " ))]').get()
```

I cannot do it. What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I changed my xpath expression and I was able now to get it finally.

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='fotorama']//a/img/@src").extract()
```

**That did the job successfully.**

But with a CSS Selector I am still not able to get the image link out of the source code.

Comment: With CSS selector it's `response.css('div.fotorama img::attr(src)').get()`. Next time this happens try to disable JavaScript in your browser and see if the classes/tags are different. Another option is to use [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#example-of-shell-session) and after fetching the response open it with `view(response)`.

Comment: You're right; Disabling JavaScript made it possible for me. This will become routine for me now. Thank you, And Scrapy Shell with view(response) gives me an error: >>> view(response): True >>> tcgetpgrp failed: Not a tty. I'll go troubleshooting.